# Определить месяцы между двумя датами

Tags: python, pyqt5

У нас есть апи, в котором указаны дата начала и дата конца выполнения определённой задачи. Обычно, каждая из задач длится на протяжении определённого числа месяцев. На данный момент есть возможность посчитать общее количество дней таким образом:

```
start_date.daysTo(end_date)
```

На выходе это даёт абсолютное количество дней и уже здесь встаёт вопрос: каким образом определить месяцы, которые находятся между этими двумя датами? То есть, например, у нас есть 12.01.2019 и 12.04.2019, и вот каким образом определить, что в эти даты попадает январь, февраль, март и апрель, ну и все прочие месяцы в зависимости от дат начала и конца?

Comment: start_date какой объект?

Comment: В апи, откуда и достаётся, хранится в формате date, если Вы об этом. DaysTo - это из PyQT5 функция.

Comment: @rolkins, нет там такого :) daysTo это метод какого-то типа, наверное qt-шного. Что показывает `print(type(start_date))`? Там может быть QDate или QDateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если `start_date` / `end_date` это [QDate](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html), то у него есть метод для получения текущего месяца - [QDate::month](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html#month), которое вернет числовое представление месяца:

```
1 = "January"
2 = "February"
3 = "March"
4 = "April"
5 = "May"
6 = "June"
7 = "July"
8 = "August"
9 = "September"
10 = "October"
11 = "November"
12 = "December"
```

Соответственно, вызываете у `start_date.month()` и `end_date.month()` и проверяете к каким месяцам они относятся.

Если же у вас там не [QDate](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html), а [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html), то будет все тоже самое, но нужно будет получить дату через [QDateTime::date()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#date): `start_date.date().month()`

---

**PS.**

У [QDate](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdate.html) и [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) есть метод `daysTo`, поэтому про них и написал.

Comment: Да-да, это как раз QDate у меня. Думал, что вдруг найдётся что-то, что бы возвращало список месяцев в данном промежутке.
Ладно, попробую как-нибудь так, спасибо :)

Comment: @rolkins, вы в следующий раз будьте внимательнее в вопросе и указывайте важную информацию, а то угадывать весело, но не всегда получается точно :)